# SQL Server trigger compare inserted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to compare the inserted table in my trigger in an IF statement.
In the first block of the IF statement, i am filtering the inserted table so that the inserted movie room number (filmzaal_zaalnummer) is equal to the movie room number in the agenda table.

The agenda table gives me 3 columns.
1) the movie room number
2) the start date_time of the movie
3) the end date_time of the movie.

So after I compared the agenda.filmzaal_zaalnummer to inserted.filmzaal_zaalnummer I am trying to find out if the inserted start date_time of the movie is between a start date_time and an end date_time of a movie that is already on the agenda.

I think that if the inserted start date_time IS NOT interrupting any other existing movies that my SELECT TOP 1 inserted.id should be empty, and that is why I am comparing it to the originally inserted id, so that if the inserted agenda is interrupting any existing movies that the IF statement will be activated and the rollback should be hit.
But now my trigger always is being activated.
How do I need to solve this?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_controlleer_afspeeldatum]
ON  [dbo].[agenda]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
if  (
        select top 1    i.id
        from    (   select filmzaal_zaalnummer, datum_tijd, DATEADD(minute,f.speelduur,datum_tijd) as eind_datum_tijd
                    from agenda a, film f
                    where a.film_titel = f.titel ) AS agenda,
                inserted i
        where   i.filmzaal_zaalnummer = agenda.filmzaal_zaalnummer 
        and     i.datum_tijd between agenda.datum_tijd and agenda.eind_datum_tijd
    ) =
    (
        select top 1    i.id
        from            inserted i
    )
    begin
    rollback transaction
    print 'Er draait dan al een film op die tijd in die zaal'
    return
    end    
END
```

Comment: You have some major logic issues here. You are using top 1 but not specifying an order by. Those results may or may not come back in the same order every time. You also need to start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: To actually be able to help with your issue we are going to need some details about the tables, the data and what you are trying to accomplish. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The reason why i use SELECT TOP 1, is because i just insert 1 record and when i dont use TOP 1 i get an error because [inserted] returns more records

Comment: Right but triggers in sql server fire once per operation, not once per row. This means if you look at only 1 row from inserted your trigger is not adequate because not every insert will always contain only a single row. It might be true today from the application standpoint but that might not always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some tips:
-use English in all of your code
-give a database schema
-give create script
-give a few succeed/fail testcases
-describe in understandable English what you want to accomplish

Two problems in your code:
1. In your query you were checking films which were already on the agenda with themselves so then there is always a duplicate. So only compare records where `agenda.id<>inserted.id`. See [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables):

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, **new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table**. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

2. You must always take into account that there could be multiple inserted records or duplicates because you can use multi-insert queries. 
   See [Create DML Triggers to Handle Multiple Rows of Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data)

Here's the correct code and a few testcases:

```
drop trigger [trg_Check_Agenda_For_Double_Bookings];
go

create TRIGGER [trg_Check_Agenda_For_Double_Bookings]
ON  agenda
after INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @count int;

    set @count = (
        select count(*) as countDuplicates
        from (
            select id,filmzaal_zaalnummer, datum_tijd, DATEADD(minute,f.speelduur,datum_tijd) as eind_datum_tijd
            from agenda a, film f
            where a.film_titel = f.titel) AS agenda, inserted i
            where   i.filmzaal_zaalnummer = agenda.filmzaal_zaalnummer 
            and     i.id<>agenda.id
            and     i.datum_tijd between agenda.datum_tijd and agenda.eind_datum_tijd
        )

    if (@count>0)
        begin
            rollback transaction
            print 'There is already a movie playing during the same time in that theatre.'
            return
        end    
END;
go

delete from agenda
--must succeed (first planned movie in agenda)
INSERT [dbo].[agenda] ([film_titel], [filmzaal_zaalnummer], [datum_tijd]                                , [taalversie], [projectie]) VALUES 
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD');

--must fail because Logan movie takes 137 minutes
INSERT [dbo].[agenda] ([film_titel], [filmzaal_zaalnummer], [datum_tijd]                                , [taalversie], [projectie]) VALUES 
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD');
INSERT [dbo].[agenda] ([film_titel], [filmzaal_zaalnummer], [datum_tijd]                                , [taalversie], [projectie]) VALUES 
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T02:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD');

--must succeed because this one is 3 hours later and Logan only takes 137 minutes
INSERT [dbo].[agenda] ([film_titel], [filmzaal_zaalnummer], [datum_tijd]                                , [taalversie], [projectie]) VALUES 
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T03:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD');

--multi insert of a good and bad planned movie (above 2 records) but both will fail because whole transaction/insert will be rolled back!
INSERT [dbo].[agenda] ([film_titel], [filmzaal_zaalnummer], [datum_tijd]                                , [taalversie], [projectie]) VALUES 
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T02:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD'),
                      (    N'Logan',                     1, CAST(N'2017-01-01T03:00:00.000' AS DateTime),    N'Engels',    N'TweeD');
```